# Query - 3 result paths, 2 results

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am in need of help understanding how to structure something.

I am attempting to write a stored proc, that takes in one variable (id), and has a couple of paths based on the result of the query.

1. if there are no rows in one of the tables I join on, it should return true (or 1)

since there are rows, check the result of the query (it just returns a count).

2. if the result from the query > 0, return true
3. if the result from the query is == 0, return false

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Yep I have, but with no luck yet.  My main problem is structure the procedure, and kickin it out if the first case returns null.

I have something like --

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM AA A
   INNER JOIN BB B ON ...
WHERE B.? = 1


So that query can return null, or 0-N, but I want to return 0/1 (t/f) based on the cases I listed above

Comment: It might help us if you show some sample data along with the desired output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you're after something like:

```
declare
  v_count1 integer;
  v_count2 integer;

  v_result Boolean;
begin
  select count(tab1.join_col) count_tab1,
         count(tab2.join_col) count_tab2
  into   v_count1, v_count2
  from   tab1
         left outer join tab2 on tab1.join_col = tab2.join_col;

  if v_count2 = 0 then
    v_result := true;
  elsif v_count1 = 0 then
    v_result := false;
  elsif v_count1 > 0 then
    v_result := true;
  end if;

  return v_result;
end;
/
```

If that's not the case, then please update your question to provide more information.

Comment: Nice this was helpful.  I ended up using something similar after a bit more research. 

Tried to format a stripped down version of my code, but the comment section is killin me